# Angular throwing cryptic error, can't figure out root cause

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a CRUD SPA with UI Router. Here's the state:

```
.state('admin', {
    url: '/admin/',
    templateUrl: 'ui/admin.html'
});
```

The link:

```
<a ui-sref="admin"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a>
```

But on clicking that link, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 1
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at fromJson (angular.js:1345)
        at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:10804)
        at angular.js:10895
        at forEach (angular.js:325)
        at transformData (angular.js:10894)
        at transformResponse (angular.js:11748)
        at processQueue (angular.js:16606)
        at angular.js:16622
        at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17913)
```

And that's confusing, because nowhere in my app am I dealing with JSON, and I can't quite figure out what I'm doing on my side that's triggering that error. At this moment, I have only one other state, which works, but I figure out it's because it isn't activated by clicking on an `ui-sref`.

So what's going on?

Comment: What happens if you remove the trailing slash? `'/admin'` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/50)

Comment: I'd actually tried that before posting the question. Same error.

Comment: My guess is that the router tries to get ui/admin.html from the server, but gets a response with a JSON content type instead, and containing invalid JSON. Open your browser dev tools, go to the network panel, and see which request and which response you get when clicking on that link.

Comment: Ahhh, yesss. I see the problem now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @JBNizet